# Facebook app - login through omniauth - OAuthException 191

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I am facing with the problem:

```
  "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
```

I set up in my app the needed keys and tokens, in the [Facebook's dev center](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) I set up `Site URL:` to `http://127.0.0.1:3001` and I am getting the error above. Also I tried to set up `App Namespace:` to `http://127.0.0.1:3001`, but I am getting error about bad address format...
When I tried to fill out he `App Domain:` and set there my localhost, again the error for the bad format...

What is the correct configuration the fabebook app with localhost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes in FB App you have to assign an IP Site/ App Domain.

- Facebook matches this url with the url of the request where it came from.
- You can not assign localhost or 127.0.0.1
- You have to enter the IP address your server. Also if it is rails then call the site with your-ip:3000 instead of localhost:3000; I use 192.168.1.154:3000
- Enter the same IP address in IP of the site and APP Domain in your FB APP Settings.
- To get your IP run ifconfig command in terminal if it is Linux or ipconfig if windows.

let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: which IP are you trying to add?

Comment: This is a wrongly accepted answer. FB does let you use localhost. But the port (:3000) should be indeed specified in Site URL (ex. http://localhost:3000/). Otherwise (http://localhost/) just won't work.

Comment: On the development machine I assigned 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/auth/facebook/callback' in **devise.rb** callback settings and it works. I have problems with the real host name in production **Heroku** hosting.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use urls, what I would do add this to your hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 dev-machine
127.0.0.1 dev-machine.com
```

Then in the facebook settings use

dev-machine.com as your App Domain

dev-machine.com:3001 as your Site URL

Comment: Hi I'm new to rails, could you please tell me how do we add the above mentioned urls as hosts to the application??

Comment: By hosts, I mean your hosts file on your local machine. This is usually in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 1):

in the facebook App Page -> the basic tab. find "Website with Facebook Login" Option.

you will find Site URL: input there put the full URL (i.e http:// localhost:3000 if you are in Development mode) [* note : not "App Domains"]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and it was incredibly frustrating.  The solution?  I wasn't actually passing parameters properly in the query string.  When I manually built my URL and submitted it using the browser, everything worked fine.  Crap.

So, essentially, if you're getting this error it may actually be a symptom of something totally unrelated to the `redirect_uri` -- it just happens to be the first error triggered when your parameters are messed up.  I hope that saves you the hours I spent on this.