# OmniAuth + Devise - Facebook provider - OAuthException 191

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

### Problem

I'm getting the following error:

```
"error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
```

It is very known and I found many different solutions to adress it and unfortunatelly any of them worked for me.

I'm trying to make it run locally in the `localhost:3000`, but can't make it work.

My configuration is a common configuration:

*config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
config.omniauth :facebook, '396783260390829', 'a504939e60c3410ed1becc44f41d4b94', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join('lib/assets/cacert.pem').to_s}}}
```

*Facebook config:*

[image]

*Routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end
```

I already tried the following approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = '`http://localhost:3000/`'
```

This one was the closest I got, because it redirect me back, but the adress was  `http://localhost:3000//users/auth/facebook/callbacks?xxx`

I already tried without the last slash `OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://localhost:3000'`, but then I got the 191.

**Approach 2**

Normal initializer, without the hack.

**Approach 3**

Set the domain in the Facebook configuration page.

**Approach 4**

Set *App Domains* to localhost

**Approach 5**

Set the Web Site in Facebook configuration to `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook`

**Approach 6**

Tryied with my ip adress instead of localhost and got the same error, but pnot in the **failure** of `OmniauthCallbacksController`, but in the `graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?`

```
redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback
```

**Result for all approaches**

In all the cases except the ones I explained inline I got

> OAuthException 191

in the failure method of OmniauthCallbackController I created to handle the callback.

Please if you know other alternatives or want to see anything else to try to help me, feel free to ask or answer.

---

Comment: You must be following some really old tutorials as the omniauth configuration with devise is done in a completely different way. Take a look at the wiki of the project, if you follow it to the letter you'll get the job done. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

Comment: Actually I took my configuration exactly from the wiki you linked, the only difference is OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE that i use to ignore ssl

Comment: But you have an `omniauth.rb` file! That does not appear on that wiki and you shouldn't need that.

Comment: If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: The solution should be posted as an answer, not as part of the question. You can post answers to your own questions and accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

As mentioned by @AshitakaI had to remove my old and deprecated `omniauth.rb`, so my final and working configuration is the following one:

*config/initializers/devise.rb*

In order to make authentication works I copied the cacert to my assets and referenced in the `devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :facebook, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'a504xxxe60cxxxxed1bexxxxf41d4b94', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join('lib/assets/cacert.pem').to_s}}}
```

*Facebook config:*

![enter image description here][1]

*Link to Facebook auth*

```
/users/auth/facebook
```

Thank you for the help, this issue took me 5 hours to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow the redirect address to be localhost. You must use a real IP address or named address.
See answer to similar question: [Facebook app - login through omniauth - OAuthException 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941031/facebook-app-login-through-omniauth-oauthexception-191)

Comment: It is not true, maybe in older versions of Facebook api!