# spring boot social cannot connect to facebook via localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to use spring-boot-starter-social-facebook to connect to facebook and print my profile name, but i dont understand why it failed.

FacebookController.java

[image]

/connect/facebookConnect.html

[image]

then on developer.facebook.com, i configured my app like this . .

[image]

[image]

I also set the appid and appsecret in applicationProperties.
then when i try to run and press 'connect', the browser loads for ~10secs and then 
in Spring Tool Suite's console it prints . . .

Exception while handling OAuth2 callback (I/O error on POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token":Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect). Redirecting to facebook connection status page.

i pasted the link in the browser and it says

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "ClbUIsKtnXt"
   }
}
```

i think i messed up configuring testapp in facebook.

SiteURL = http://localhost:8080/

Valid Oauth redirect = http://localhost:8080/connect/facebook

what should i do?
thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941031/facebook-app-login-through-omniauth-oauthexception-191

Answer (score 2):

Try add localhost to app domains - my setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give IP address instead of local host.

Following link you can find same information

[Facebook app - login through omniauth - OAuthException 191](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941031/facebook-app-login-through-omniauth-oauthexception-191)

Answer (score 0):

You should filled in **Domains** not localhost , like this
[image]

and you can configuration you System file **hosts** turn to 127.0.0.1 for local testing.